Authenticated UI parts should be update in SSR
I'm using Supabase SSR (OAuth) for authentication and need to update UI components based on the authentication status. For instance, if the user is not logged in, a "Login" button should appear in the navigation bar; otherwise, it should display the "user profile."
This is my Auth Context API:
const AuthContext = createContext<any>(undefined);

export const useAuth = () => {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) {
    throw new Error('');
  }
  return context;
};

export function AuthProvider({ children }: any) {
  const supabase = createClient()

  const [authUser, setAuthUser] = useState<any>();
  const getUser = async function getUser() {
    const {
      data: { user },
    } = await supabase.auth.getUser()
    setAuthUser(user)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getUser();
  }, []); // Missing dependency 'getUser' is noted here.

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authUser, setAuthUser }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}

This is my menu component:
useEffect(() => {
  let nTabs = [
    ...initTabs.map(x => {
      return x;
    }),
  ];
  setActiveIndex(null)
  if (authUser && authUser.user_metadata) {
    nTabs.push({ name: t("tab3") });
  } else if (nTabs.length === 3) {
    nTabs.pop();
  }

  let pos =
    pathName === '/${locale}' || pathName === '/' 
      ? 0
      : pathName === '/${locale}/user/palettes' || pathName === '/user/palettes'
        ? 2
        : pathName.startsWith('/${locale}/color_code') || pathName.startsWith('/color_code') 
          ? 1
          : null;

  if (pos !== null && nTabs[pos]) {
    setActiveIndex(pos);
  }

  setTabs(nTabs);
}, [pathName, router, authUser]); // React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'initTabs', 'locale', 't'.

However, it's not functioning correctly; authenticated content is delayed even when logged in.
The authenticated content should behave like SSR, working without delay.

Supabase SSR I believe does not have a createClient method, but instead has usage specific client methods like createBrowserClient or createServerClient. Please refer to our docs on how to properly use them.
https://supabase.com/docs/guides/auth/server-side/nextjs
